# OpenLayers plugin displays OSM in infra-red

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-openlayers-plugin

In QGIS, I try to add OpenStreetMap as a base layer with OpenLayers plugin > OpenStreetMap > OpenStreetMap but it only displays in infra-red.  Is there a way to solve this?

[image]

The Apple maps base layer, by contrast, displays normally: [image]

Comment: I'm not seeing that. Which OSM server are you hitting?

Comment: I'm not sure how you check which server

Comment: Try the QuickMapServices plugin. It has less issues, and is actively maintained.